# BeautifulSoupで要素内の要素を取得したい

Tags: python3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

PythonでBeautifulSoupを使って、findを使って特定のclassのテキストを取得しようと思ったのですが、違うクラスの中の特定のクラスも取得してしまうので、二回findを使おうと思ったのですが、エラーが出てきてしまいました。

ソースコード

```
<div class="hoge">
    <div class="piyo"></div>
</div>
<div class="hogehoge">
    <div class="piyo"></div>
</div>
```

これのhogeの中のpiyoだけを取得したいのですが、

```
soup.find_all('div', 'hoge').find('div', 'piyo')
```

と

```
 ex = soup.find_all('div', 'hoge')
    ex.find_all('div', 'piyo')
```

を試したのですがうまくいきませんでした。
何か良い方法はありませんか？
初心者ですみません。

追記
エラーはこのように出ました。

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: どのようなエラーが発生しましたか？

Comment: @ernix 今追加しました

Comment: 追記されたエラーが質問のコードと一致していないようにみえますが……

Comment: コードの一部ではなくコード全体をお見せいただけますか？（URLなどはマスクして構いません）

Comment: 参考までに、`select()` メソッドと CSS selector を使って同じ事が可能です。`soup.select('div[class="hoge"] div[class="piyo"]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ドキュメント](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous)に

> `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This usually happens because you expected `find_all()` to return a single tag or string. But `find_all()` returns a *list* of tags and strings–a ResultSet object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the .foo of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

とある通りです．`find_all()`を使う場合，その結果はリストで得られるのでイテレーションをまわしてやればいいでしょう．例えば

```
for hoge in soup.find_all('div', class_='hoge'):
    print(hoge.find_all('div', class_='piyo'))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！今自分でもリストのことを忘れていて、改修したらできました！ご協力ありがとうございました

Comment: 未来のエンジニア さん、解決できたら回答を承認していただけますか？